# Formatting date using moment.js using locale rather than explicit format

Tags: datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

Our dates from our date selector are in *DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A* format.
Currently, we need to supply a format explicitly to moment.js in order to have this date correctly interpreted as follows:

```
var dateFormats = ['DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A'];
var tmp1 = moment(date, dateFormats).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Our preference would be to avoid hardcoding dateformats and instead be able to apply the locale as follows:

```
var locale = (window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language).toLowerCase();
moment.locale(locale);
var tmp1 = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Currently, executing the following (after applying the locale above):

```
moment('15/12/2016 2:27 PM').format('YYYY/MM/DD h:mm A');
```

gives:

```
"2017/03/12 2:27 PM"
```

When it needs to give:

```
"2016/12/15 2:27 PM"
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input string has a locale specific format, you can use moment's [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) to parse it. Using `longDateFormat(dateFormat);` you can get localized format.

Here a working example using en-au locale:

```js
moment.locale('en-au');
var input = '15/12/2016 2:27 PM';
var s = moment(input).format('YYYY/MM/DD h:mm A'); // Gives Deprecation warning
console.log(s); // Invalid date

// Get locale data
var localeData = moment.localeData();
var format = localeData.longDateFormat('L') + ' ' + localeData.longDateFormat('LT');
s = moment(input, format).format('YYYY/MM/DD h:mm A');
console.log(s); // 2016/12/15 2:27 PM
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```